# add preload for fonts in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, css

I want to add below in the head of Magento 2 via default.xml, unable to get the exact syntax for same

```
 <link rel="preload" href="https://example.com/static/version1580127835/frontend/theme/theme_more/en_US/css/fonts/Museo-500.otf" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

currently css are added to website like below

Comment: Use this module https://github.com/meanbee/magento2-csspreload

Answer (score 5):

As of Magento 2.3.3 this can be achieved with the `<font>` head type.

Documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html#font-head-type

Reference implementation (from Luma):

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.6/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml#L11-L15

Comment: I added some fonts into my custom theme exactly how they did it in Luma: (layout/default_head_blocks.xml) and get this error: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'font': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ).
Line: 28. Why?  
So I'll just add to a phtml template I guess. Also, great documentation as always m2 ⼢

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible out the box using layout XML, the best options seem to be either manually doing so in a template which isn't great, or using a plugin such as https://github.com/meanbee/magento2-csspreload which allows you to do this:

```
<referenceBlock name="head.csspreload">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="assets" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="unique_name" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="path" xsi:type="string">css/filename.css</item>
                <item name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="name" xsi:type="string">attribute</item>
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: How can I use the font-family in CSS after it is defined in layout xml ? Should I declare it somewhere else ?

Comment: Can you ask a new question for this please?

Comment: It's a specific question for this subject. I added the font using the meanbee/magento2-csspreload, I see it in source of the page, but I'm not able to use it in a CSS file. The question is how can I use the font-family of the font that I added using above XML in a CSS file ?

Answer (score 1):

For some one who use https://github.com/meanbee/magento2-csspreload, this module could make an issue with MIME type when try to add fonts.

To fix this, you could custom the *link_template*

```
<argument name="link_template" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<link rel="preload" as="font" crossorigin href=":path:" :attributes: />]]></argument>
```

Full code will look like this:

```
<referenceBlock name="head.csspreload">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="assets" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fa_solid_900" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="path" xsi:type="string">plugins/font-awesome/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2</item>
                        <item name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">attribute</item>
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="lora_v16_latin_regular" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="path" xsi:type="string">fonts/Lora/lora-v16-latin-regular.woff2</item>
                        <item name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">attribute</item>
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="lora_v16_latin_700" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="path" xsi:type="string">fonts/Lora/lora-v16-latin-700.woff2</item>
                        <item name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">attribute</item>
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="luma_icons" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="path" xsi:type="string">fonts/Luma-Icons.woff2</item>
                        <item name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">attribute</item>
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="fa_brands_400" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="path" xsi:type="string">plugins/font-awesome/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2</item>
                        <item name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">attribute</item>
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <argument name="link_template" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<link rel="preload" as="font" crossorigin href=":path:" :attributes: />]]></argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: How can I use the font-family in CSS after it is defined in layout xml ?
Should I declare it somewhere else ?

Comment: @Eugen, yea, if you need to use custom font-family, then you need to download and add that font in your project. You can search "how to use custom font in magento 2" in google to have detail instruction.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question ... I added the font using the above XML because I'm interested to load it using rel="preload", not using @font-face in a CSS file ... 

I added the font using the meanbee/magento2-csspreload, I see it in source of the page, but I'm not able to use it in a CSS file. The question is how can I use the font-family in a CSS file of the font that I added using above XML ?